# Primefaces confirmdialog doesnt call backingbean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

For my web-application i wanted to show a datatable with the option to edit, delete and add new sets of Data.
Showing the data and using in-line-editing proved to be no problem.
Upon deletion some kind of confirmation needs to be done, so i added a confirm-dialog to the button.
However, when i added a second dialog for the add mechanism, the confirm-dialog suddenly didn't trigger the delete action anymore.
So i tried to reduce the code as much as possible and found out, that, depending on the order of the dialogs, the second dialog never triggers the associated action anymore.

Here's the reduced template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<ui:composition template="/templates/abstractLayout.xhtml"> 
    <ui:define name="contentBase">
        <p:dialog header="Does Work" widgetVar="inputDialog" modal="true">
            <h:form id="addRolleForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <p:commandButton id="addRolle" value="Do it" action="#{testView.works}" oncomplete="PF('inputDialog').hide();"/>
            <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="cancel" onclick="PF('inputDialog').hide();"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
        <h:form id="test">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <p:commandLink id="deleteLink" styleClass="editCell ui-icon ui-icon-trash" action="#{testView.doesntWork}" title="Delete" process="@all">
                <p:confirm header="confirm" message="Yes doesnt activate action" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="openInputDlg" title="Work work work" icon="ui-icon-plus" onclick="PF('inputDialog').show();" type="button"/>
        <p:confirmDialog global="true">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

and now the associated view behind:

```
/*package and imports*/
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestView {

    GenericLogger log = new GenericLogger(this);

    public void works() {
        log.logEnter("Works");
        log.logReturn("Work returned");
    }

    public void doesntWork() {
        log.logEnter("DOES Work"); //never enters this method
        log.logReturn("DID return");

    }
}
```

Each dialog functions properly by itself, if i remove the other one.
I already tried to put the commandbuttons of the confirmdialog in their own form, but this didnt change anything.

Searching the forums or the net shows me tons of other situations, none of which apply to mine. Any help with this issue is appreciated

Comment: It seems, both hidden input fields get the same name and same value.
My suggestion for a delete link is: `partialSubmit="true" process="@this"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be the cause for the issues.

Comment: The field names or the process value?

Comment: Couldnt change the field names, so i changed the process value to @form